# Combined and individual probability of two continuous standard normal variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be a standard normal random variable and $Y = X^2$.
How to compute their combined and individual probabilities?

$1. P(0<X<1,Y>1)?$

$2. P(0<X<1)?$

$3. P(Y>1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a case when $X \in (0,1)$ and at the same time $Y=X^2>1$. This will never happen, because if $X^2 > 1$ then $X>1$. So the probability is $0$.
2. $P(0<X<1) = F_X(1) - F_X(0) = 0.84134475-0.5 = 0.34134475$ (for CDF values of standard normal distribution use calculator like [this one](https://www.danielsoper.com/statcalc/calculator.aspx?id=55))
3. $P(Y>1)=P(X^2>1)=P(X>1)+P(X<-1)=2*(1-P(X\leq 1))=2*(1-F_X(1))=2*(1-0.84134475)=0.31731$

Comment: Please upvote the question as I'll not be able to further ask questions if my question is downvoted. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I updated the 3rd one. You need to include also negative values below -1. Btw you can also see it as a chi-square distribution for which you can use CDF for chi-square (https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~mbognar/applets/chisq.html).